# Check words in data frame

Tags: r, lapply

I have two dataframes A and B. I want to check whether unique words of data frame A exist in dataframe B. If exist, retain that word, otherwise remove word from each rows of dataframe B.

```
A <- data.frame(name = c(
  "X-ray right leg arteries",
  "consultation of gynecologist",
  "x-ray leg arteries",
  "x-ray leg with 20km distance"
), stringsAsFactors = F)

B <- data.frame(name = c(
  "X-ray left leg arteries",
  "consultation (inspection) of gynecalogist",
  "MRI right leg arteries",
  "X-ray right leg arteries with special care"
), stringsAsFactors = F)


k=unique(unlist(strsplit(A$name, " ")))
d = do.call(rbind, lapply(B$name, function(z) {
  xx = lapply(lapply(k, function(x) grepl(x, unlist(strsplit(z, " ")), fixed = T)), which)
  paste(k[sapply(xx, function(x) length(x)>0)], collapse = " ")
}
))
```

I have already solved it. Just wanted to know if there is an efficient way to do it as I have more than 15K rows in my real dataset.

Comment: One option is to change the `sapply(xx, function(x) length(x) > 0)` to `lengths(xx) > 0` which will be more faster

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of multiple loops, we could extract the unique words from 'B' using the 'k' and then `paste` those elements together

```
library(stringr)
unlist(lapply(str_extract_all(B$name, paste(k, collapse="|")), 
             paste, collapse=' '))
```